# Where is my PATH?

Tags: unix, .bash-profile

When I run the following command, I see several paths and all looks well.

```
echo $PATH
```

However, I want to find out where these paths are stored.

I have looked for `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc` but they don't exist.

Comment: It's more or less distro (and shell) specific. For example: https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/filesystem/trunk/profile https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/9d6e6fd31dbb2504559325d6aa947e3bb64f9a8c/trunk/PKGBUILD#L46

Comment: https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in `/etc/profile`.

"`/etc/profile` contains Linux system wide environment and startup programs. It is used by all users with bash, ksh, sh shell. Usually used to set PATH variable, user limits, and other settings for user. It only runs for login shell." (https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/profile)